# Making an object move - Object oriented - JAVA

Tags: java, object

Trying to get an object to move to the left of the screen, but I'm unable to.
Using these two classes(got a third separate class just to start the program).

```
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.Font;
import java.util.Random;

import javax.swing.ImageIcon;
import javax.swing.JLabel;

import gu2.PaintWindow_GU2;
import paintpanel.Text;

public class Race {
//Instansvariabler
private PaintWindow_GU2 window;
private Car car1;
private Car car2;
private ImageIcon image = new ImageIcon("images/RacingTrack.png");
Random rand = new Random();
private int x;
private int x2;
Font font = new Font("SansSerif",Font.PLAIN,24);


//Konstruktor som använder sig av variablerna window, car1 och car2
public Race(PaintWindow_GU2 window,Car car1, Car car2){
this.window = window;
this.car1 = car1;
this.car2 = car2;


}

//Action-metosd för att starta racet
public void action(){
window.addIcon(image, 50, 50, true);
window.addIcon(car1.getImage(), car1.getX(), car1.getY(), true);
window.addIcon(car2.getImage(), 600, 205, true);
while(true){    
car1.moveTo(600-5, 165);    
window.setIconXY(car1.getImage(), car1.getX(), car1.getY());






}
}
}
import javax.swing.ImageIcon;

public class Car {
    private ImageIcon image;
    private int x;
    private int y;

    public Car(ImageIcon image) {
        this.image = image;
    }

    public ImageIcon getImage() {
        return image;
    }

    public int getX() {
        return x;
    }

    public int getY() {
        return y;
    }

    public void moveTo(int x, int y) {
        this.x = x;
        this.y = y;
    }
}
```

So I'm missing some code in the action method, but I'm not sure how to get the object to move to the left.
Any help to get the object to move to the left would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: I suggest you add a task to the Event loop to move the Car once for each movement and allow the GUI Thread to update the display between actions.

Comment: Any good way of doing that? I managed to move the car to the left earlier but it went straight back to its starting position.

Comment: yes. You add a Timer which moves it once each time the action is called. Plenty of tutorials on how to do animation.